# Getting error when ruby webpack installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to install ruby webpack. But getting an error it says "C:\Ruby31-x64\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- F:/Rails (LoadError)"

How can I fix this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyKJ5.png)

Looking for install webpack correctly

Comment: First: Please provide the command and error as TEXT not image. It's just mor convinient to work with. 
Second: Try `bundle exec rails <command>`.

Comment: Hi Here my command "rails webpacker:install"
And this is what I got " C:\Ruby31-x64\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- F:/Rails (LoadError)"

Comment: I tried " bundle exec rails webpacker:install" But still getting same error

Comment: Did you install rails? And how did you?

Comment: Yes This is what I did.

I added gem 'webpacker' , github: 'rails/webpacker' to my gem file. Then I run bundle and lastly run rails webpacker:install. – 
Then I got error it says "$ rails webpacker:install Warning: you are using an unstable release of Node.js (v19.1.0). If you encounter issues with Node.js, consider switching to an Active LTS release. More info: docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-node " – 
Next I changed nvm version to lts version and run above command.

Comment: After that I got this error which is "$ rails webpacker:install C:\Ruby31-x64\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- F:/Rails (LoadError)"

Comment: I have Rails 7.0.4, ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x64-mingw-ucrt]; node v18.12.1